# Qt creator - .ui form displaying in new window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qwidget

I'm in the process of creating a GUI in Qt creator. Right now I have different .ui forms that correspond with different parts of my GUI. My login.ui window appears when you first run the program. When you click the loginButton, a new window displays with my MainMenuScreen.ui form. My problem is I don't want the MainMenuScreen to open in a new window...I want the application to only have one window and the contents change...any way I can do this by keeping separate .ui forms and without using StackedWidgets? My LoginScreen.ui and MainMenuScreen.ui both extend QWidget and in my Login.cpp I have an onclick event function which calls show() and creates the new window of my MainMenuScreen.

Thanks!

Comment: Why no to using StackedWidgets? That seems to me the way to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: @ksming I'm already using StackedWidgets in my MainMenuScreen for the different options in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just call the [setCentralWidget()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) method of your QMainWindow to reset the widget that is displayed in the Window.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm working on implementing it that way now. My only problem is now I have a MainWindow which calls setCentralWidget(LoginScreen) and from the LoginScreen when I try and setCentralWidget(MainMenu) it won't work. I tried to call it from MainWindow again with an if/else for when the user clicks the LoginOption but it's not working. I'm trying to play around and see how I can setCentralWidget() from a class other than the MainWindow, if that makes sense.